# Fixing, TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, video, stream, raspberry-pi3

Streaming video from Raspberry Pi to 192.168.0.6:8081 using this code...

***[Edited based on Comments & Daniel]***

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket


class VideoStreamingTest(object):
def __init__(self):

    #self.server_socket = socket.socket()
    #self.server_socket.bind(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    #self.server_socket.listen(0)

    #self.connection, self.client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
    #self.connection = self.connection.makefile('rb')
    #self.streaming()
    self.socket = socket.socket()
    self.connection = self.socket.connect(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    #self.socket.connect(('192.168.0.6', 8081))
    self.streaming()

def streaming(self):

    try:
        #print ("Connection from: ", self.client_address)
        print ("Streaming...")
        print ("Press 'q' to exit")

        stream_bytes = b' '
        while True:

            stream_bytes += self.socket.recv(1024)
            first = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
            last = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
            if first != -1 and last != -1:
                jpg = stream_bytes[first:last + 2]
                stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last + 2:]
                #image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
                image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
                cv2.imshow('image', image)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
    finally:
        #self.connection.close()
        self.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoStreamingTest()
```

***However I am getting the following errors: (edited) :( ***

```
Streaming...
Press 'q' to exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 48, in <module>
VideoStreamingTest()
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 19, in __init__
self.streaming()
  File "C:/Users/tiger/Desktop/take_the_stream_from_pi.py", line 32, in streaming
first = stream_bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How do I tackle this ?
*(**PS**: Trying to open a streamed window from pi camera(which works on 192.168.0.6:8081 on my web browser) to my PC with this program)*

Comment: just remove `self.connection.close()` from your code. `socket` object handles the closing already. No need to close the integer handle.

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong, but not sure if it's because of cut/paste or genuine bug.

Comment: define `stream_bytes = b' '` (bytes, not string). But you heavily edited your question, which invalidates answers (& comments)

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

thats what I'm getting now

Comment: I had no choice because people who face similar issues can refer to the question time after time. I do apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect_ex` returns an integer, which is an error code or 0 if there is no error. You need to read via the socket itself, not on the result of that call.

Also note, as mentioned in the docs, there is no `read` method; it is call `recv`.

```
stream_bytes += self.socket.recv(1024)
```

Also, as noted in the comments, you don't need to call `self.connection.close`, for the same reason.

Comment: More to the point, `connect_ex` doesn't return any kind of connection object; rather, whether or not the socket is connected is part of the state of the object, which `connect_ex` mutates.

Comment: OP edited his question again. Now the issue lies in `stream_bytes = ' '` which should be `stream_bytes = b' '` because the output of `recv` is binary.